# selenium web scraping variable empty even though inspect element show correct place

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

I have this line `coin_name = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//tbody[1]/tr/td[3]/div/div[2]/a[1]')` for [CoinGecko](https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/recently_added)
But the variable it empty - why?

Answer (score 0):

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
driver.get("https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/recently_added")

coin_names=wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//tbody[1]/tr/td[3]/div/div[2]/a[1]')))
for coin in coin_names:
    print(coin.text)
```

Did you wait for the elements to come up. Also since you used driver.find_elements I am assuming you want a list.

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Outputs:

```
Empire Capital Token
BlackPoker
MAGIC BNB
Traders Global Business
SuperMegaHyperDoge
Zeronauts
DopeWarz
YESorNO
Dawn Wars
Plastiks
KaraStar UMY
Orne
Spintop
Charm
Crystal Wallet
Bitcoin BR
Solar Full Cycle
Shinomics
Defender of Doge
Doge Rise Up
Polkago
Aurora token
Trick
AvaPay
Andromeda
Yooshiba Inu
xSuter
Coxswap
Small Fish Cookie
BuffSwap
Kanga Exchange
MetaGaming
NFTinder
Peoplez
The Monopolist
Index Coop - ETH 2x Flexible Leverage Index (Polygon)
KingPad
Zodium
Family
Metaverse Exchange
Victoria VR
MooMonster
Decentral Games Governance
Infam
Xolo Inu
Decentral Games
Multiverse Capital
Drachen Lord
Studio Shibli
CheeseDAO
Xeebster
DiamondShiba
Ohm Inu DAO
GamingShiba
Honey Deluxe
OOOOR Finance
Wizards And Dragons
Return of The King
Devia8
Umami Finance
TerraKub
Big Fund Capital DAO
Stamen Tellus Token
Harmony Parrot Egg
Luxy
Doge Raca
FireFlame Inu
TerraUSD (Wormhole)
WAGMI Game
Cryptogram
AngryFloki
4JNET
GizaDao
DoragonLand
Moonscape
Lord Arena
WidiLand
Witnet
Kiradoge
Solidray Finance
Fenix Danjon
Dogelana
Santos FC Fan Token
Integritee
Kardia Info
Governance OHM
MINE Network
StraitsX Indonesia Rupiah
Income Island
SuperPlayer World
ForthBox
Txbit
StaFi rATOM
Juicebox
Foxboy
ImpactXP
Miaw
ShopNEXT
Creaticles
Kaizilla
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.
But it's not that because elements before and elements after are loading it's just this one. Can you look at https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/recently_added to find maybe I missed something at the element location?

Comment: What value did you want printed? Can you highlight it with a screenshot or something.

Comment: the name of the coin, follow the link and inspect element //tbody[1]/tr/td[3]/div/div[2]/a[1]   to see, for some reason that I can not find why, it's coming empty

Comment: That xpath gives me about 100 elements.

Comment: yes but the variable is empty, it can not bring the text from //tbody[1]/tr/td[3]/div/div[2]/a[1]